# Why uploaded photo is much smaller than saved - Delphi 10.3.2, firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 10.3.2
I do not understand this situations:

1)
Uploading photo about 1M

```
image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('test.jpg');
```

Then I save the same photo

```
image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile('test_new.jpg');
```

and test_new.jpg is about 3M.  Why ???

2)

I want to send a photo from the TImage (test1.jpg - 1MB) object using IdHTTP and POST request to server.
I use the function Base64_Encoding_stream to encode image. 
Image size (string) after encoding the function is 20 MB! ? Why if the original file has 1MB ?

```
function Base64_Encoding_stream(_image:Timage): string;
var
  base64: TIdEncoderMIME;
  output: string;
  stream_image : TStream;
begin
    try
      begin
        base64 := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
        stream_image := TMemoryStream.Create;
        _image.Bitmap.SaveToStream(stream_image);
        stream_image.Position := 0;
        output := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(stream_image);
        stream_image.Free;
        base64.Free;
        if not(output = '') then
        begin
          Result := output;
        end
        else
        begin
          Result := 'Error';
        end;
      end;
    except
      begin
        Result := 'Error'
      end;
    end;
 end;


....

img_encoded := Base64_Encoding_stream(Image1);

.....

procedure Send(_json:String );
var
  lHTTP             : TIdHTTP;
  PostData          : TStringList;
begin
  PostData := TStringList.Create;
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
      PostData.Add('dane='  + _json );
      lHTTP.Request.UserAgent   :=   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
      lHTTP.Request.Connection  := 'keep-alive';
      lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      lHTTP.Request.Charset     := 'utf-8';
      lHTTP.Request.Method      := 'POST';

    _dane := lHTTP.Post('http://......./add_photo.php',PostData);

  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    PostData.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I don't believe `image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('test.jpg');` would actually works if your image was an actual JPEG. Why the file triple in size?  Best guess, you load an 8 bits bitmap and you save it back as a 24 bits bitmap.

Comment: @KenBourassa the OP is using FireMonkey. The FMX `TBitmap` [supports JPEG images, amongst others](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats). The VCL `TBitmap` only supports BMP images.

Comment: @KenBourassa   I checked. The input photo has 24 bits and the output one too

Comment: @Olaf There is no possible way that a 1MB file would bloat to 20MB when base64-encoded. It would bloat to only ~1.3MB. The file would have to be 15MB to bloat to 20MB in base64. So you have to be doing something very wrong, but you did not show all of your code. But why are you using base64 at all? HTTP can post binary data, just post the JPG file as-is.

Comment: @Remy  Because I would like to send the photo and other parameters as JSON - string. That's how I send data using PHP between websites.

Comment: @Olaf I would not use JSON for this, MIME (via `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`) would make more sense, as it can carry both text and binary at the same time, it is the format used by web browsers when submitting upload webforms, and `TIdHTTP` has native support for that format via its `TIdHTTP.Post(TIdMultipartFormDataStream)` method. Either way, please [edit] your question to show your `TIdHTTP` code.

Comment: I notice in the help it mentions `LoadFromFile` can fail silently under some conditions. Wouldn't hurt to double check the image you want is getting loaded and you are not saving some other image.

Comment: @Remy - edited. I will read about TIdMultipartFormDataStream. Thank you

Comment: @Brian "*I notice in the help it mentions `LoadFromFile` can fail silently under some conditions.*" - yeah, FMX's error handling is vastly inferior to VCL's error handling. It is really hard to know sometimes when things go wrong in FMX.

Comment: @olaf Regarding ‘SaveToFile’ size: best guess you have a bitmap in memory which is being encoded to jpeg during save and the resulting size of the jpeg depends on the quality of the jpeg and the compression engine used to create the jpeg. Myself Ive noticed that jpeg from a camera usually get  alot bigger when loading to bitmap and then resavind to jpeg. Therefor it’s best to use the actual jpegfile and send that as a stream.

Comment: @R.  Yes, Exactly. I'm coming to that. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post your original file using base64 you can basically use your own code. You only need to change the used stream inside your base64 encoding routine like this:

```
function Base64_Encoding_stream(const filename: string): string;
var
  stream_image : TStream;
begin
  try
    // create read-only stream to access the file data
    stream_image := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    // the stream position will be ‘0’, so no need to set that
    Try
      Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(stream_image);
    Finally
      stream_image.Free;
    End;
    if length(result) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := 'Error';
    end;
  except
    Result := 'Error'
  end;
end;
```

Also, I refactored your code a bit with some try/finally sections, to ensure no memory leaks when errors occur. And I removed the begin/end inside the try/except as those are not needed.

Also removed the local string variable to avoid double string allocation and the unnecessary construction of the `TIdEncoderMIME` base64 object.

Comment: thank you. I still have a question. How is the best way reduce a bitmap to a specific size.
New phones take pictures in high resolution. This photo I get as BITMAP. 
Instead of sending a 4032x1908 size,  I would like to send a 1344x635 pictue size. I tried to use the bitmap.resize method but it works poorly.

Comment: And one more thing. Is it worth / can I use compression, e.g. GZIP, when sending data using IdHTTP? How to make the time to upload a photo to a minimum?

Comment: @olaf sorry, I do not have knowledge of a specific better image resizing routine.

Comment: @olaf compression depends on what the server can do and what libs you have. Also jpeg wont compress well, so the gain will be minimal.

Comment: Why do you create and free `base64`, and not use it?

Comment: @nolaspeaker I copied the code from the OP, but did not notice this. I updated the answer to NOT use the constructed base64 object, as `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream` is a class method and therefor does not require you te create an object of `TIdEncoderMIME'.